# Manually input orders in woocommerce databases?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question about manually inputting information in a MySQL databases (specifically in meaning Woocommerce order databases). I have some orders, that I get from another database and have to input them in in a Woocommerce database, which by now I found out that it consists out of several different ones, and not from just one. The Woocommerce is a plugin in Wordpress. Does anybody have any idea on how that could be done? 
Some additional information: I am working with Wordpress 4.4.2 and Woocommerce 2.5.5.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to directly insert data into woocommerce's database because this method is not really documented and would require intricate knowledge of woocommerce's database.

I would rather use woocommerce's [rest api to create the orders](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-an-order). The documentation has examples for various programming languages. There is another bulk creation api as well, but found no examples on how exactly to use that one, since the example in the documentation is on bulk updates only.

Comment: so lets say i have a database in of some orders saved in a MySQL database. How would i do this with lets say PYthon or something... I am not talking about code but hipothetical answer...

Comment: I would send an http request to the specified API point with the required parameters. The API will take care of creating the order within woocommerce and return back its id to the caller application.

Comment: ok, sory, but im not that good to understand that... could you explain a little bit more in details, maybe with an example. It would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Pls check out the examples in the linked documentation first, I do not realky have anything to add to them.